# Iterate from multi-dimension array in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

How to iterate from this multi-dimensional array in iOS ?
This data is coming from JSON

```
(
        (
        "burger meal",
        "getImage.ashx?id=1",
        150,
        300,
        "get a free burger"
    ),
        (
        "chinese combo",
        "getImage.ashx?id=2",
        350,
        700,
        "get  a combo free"
    ),
        (
        "cheeese cake",
        "getImage.ashx?id=3",
        350,
        700,
        "get a cake free with meal"
    )
)
```

I need to use object at index 3 e.g. = 150,350,350 in UITableView .

I have tried this

```
NSArray *array = jsonArray;

for (NSArray *newArray in array) { 
    [newArray addObjectFromArray:array];
}
```

Comment: so ... whats your code for this ... had you tried anything??

Comment: have you tried like : array[0][3] ?

Comment: In order to answer the question, however, you need to explain that the data should be extracted from that (JSON?) data into an instance variable, therefore you need to explain when that ivar should be allocated before actually showing the iteration.  A complete answer will then be answered by the OP with "i cannot get to work".

Comment: Do you need to combine all the strings at index 2 (third index is 2, not 3. 0,1,2)? Or do you need each of these strings for each of the cell in your tableview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple. Let TableView iterate the arrays for you. Your tableView is already iterating, don't add to overhead by iterating over the array yourself. You will just waste processing power if you do.

First, modify your `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate method like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  [jsonArray count]; //Provide your json array here.
}
```

Then you have to do this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Do everything that you need to do to get the cell. Here we will deal with only string retrieval from json array.
    if(jsonArray count]>indexPath.row){
        NSArray *innerArray = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //You got the inner array
        if(innerArray count]>2){
             NSString *yourDesiredString = [innerArray objectAtIndex:2]; //You got the string. Use it now as you wish. It will be 150 for the first cell, 350 for the second and 350 for the third one as well.
         }

    }

}
```

<s>I have not added any exception checks here, that's what you have to do yourself</s>. I have added basic checks to prevent crashes in case of irrelevant data, you should expand on that.

This is with the assumption that you wish to set this string to each cell. If I have misunderstood your question or you need to ask something, leave a comment

Answer (score 2):

Try This, In this code arrResult contain all values have you required at particular position.

```
NSArray *array = jsonArray;
NSMutableArray *arrResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSArray *newArray in array) { 
        [arrResult addObject:[newArray objectAtIndex:2]];

}
```

Comment: Why iterate over the array again when you already have a tableview going?

Comment: because they need all value at particular position at once.

Comment: You can get it in TableView as well. TableView is operating on IndexPath.row, use it as index.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with taking relevant data from the JSON-deserialised data structures and validating them before setting them as the datasource.  Of course this answer shows none of this validation (i.e. how many elements in the inner array) and like your answer will crash badly as soon as duff data is received.